# IOS UI below top bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, iphone-x

I'm creating a snapchat style app and I'm trying to keep UI below the top status bar (Signal/Time / Battery bar). I have it working on test phones except for iPhone X. I'm not sure if I should be using the extend under top bars / bottom bars feature or not. Is there a way to keep the UI underneath the status bar for all iPhones?

Pre iPhoneX status bar:

[image: Pre iPhoneX status bar]

iPhone X status bar:

[image: iPhone X status bar]

Comment: A few questions because your question is rather vague, without enough detail. (1) Are you using auto layout? That should really be a "yes". (2) Your screenshots show anything *but* an iPhone X "notch". Why are you tagging it as such? (3) Interface Builder - IB, Storyboard - or code? (4) If code, can you show us some? (5) If not code, can you show us the auto layout constraints? (6) If not auto layout constraints, could you show us frames? (7) If frame - well, even if not, could you give us details about devices - iPad, iPhone, iPhone X - and orientation? These things help us duplicate! Thanks.

Comment: 1. Yes I am
2. Screenshots on iPhone X do not use the notch.

Comment: You're right. Are you using safe areas? Most of my constraints - sorry, all of mine - are written in code. If you aren't using safe areas, that's the issue. If your constraints are in code, I'll post mine. But if it's in IB, sorry - but I think there's a checkbox someplace to handle it. Search (here or more like on Google) for "Auto layout safe area storyboard" and you should find it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Fixed issue in XCode in the storboard editor by changing the "View As: iPhone model" feature. From there I'm able to modify the UI for each different phone / tablet model.

Comment: Glad you found something that works! I stand by the comment I just posted - if you aren't using safe areas, look into it.